# ¿Por qué para crear las palabras para "la cualidad de ser algo", algunas se hace con el sufijo -ez y otras con el sufijo -idad? ¿Existe alguna regla?

Tags: gramática

Para crear las palabras que signifiquen "la cualidad de ser algo(x)", para algunas palabras se utiliza el sufijo -ez y para otras se utiliza el sufijo -idad. Por ejemplo:

> Impulsividad: Cualidad de la persona o la cosa que es impulsiva.

[Impulsividad significado](https://www.google.com/search?q=impulsividad%20significado&source=hp&ei=zurFYtDAJe6J5OUPtPiA2A8&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYsX43oATsOiBajolnE2Y0xBn5TIEJMyJ&ved=0ahUKEwjQ3_zQh-X4AhXuBLkGHTQ8APsQ4dUDCAc&uact=5&oq=impulsividad%20significado&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyCggAEIAEEEYQ-QEyBggAEB4QFjIGCAAQHhAWMgYIABAeEBYyCAgAEB4QDxAWMggIABAeEA8QFjIICAAQHhAPEBYyCAgAEB4QDxAWMggIABAeEA8QFjIICAAQHhAPEBY6BAgAEEM6CwgAEIAEELEDEIMBOggILhCxAxCDAToICAAQsQMQgwE6EQguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBEKMCOgsILhCABBCxAxCDAToKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzoECC4QQzoFCAAQgAQ6CggAEOoCELQCEEM6CwguEIAEEMcBEK8BOgkIABBDEEYQ-QE6EQguEIAEELEDEIMBEMcBEK8BOggIABCABBCxAzoMCAAQsQMQQxBGEPkBOgcIABDJAxBDOgcIABCxAxBDOgcIABCABBAKOgUIIRCgAVAAWK4oYPApaAVwAHgCgAHlAYgBph2SAQY0LjI0LjGYAQCgAQGwAQo&sclient=gws-wiz)

> Delgadez: Cualidad de delgado

[Delgadez significado](https://www.google.com/search?q=delgadez%20&source=hp&ei=purFYt_LCc2V5OUP5qez8Aw&iflsig=AJiK0e8AAAAAYsX4tn93wJo0DmUnjoEv52WeD-IJeW0t&ved=0ahUKEwjftte9h-X4AhXNCrkGHebTDM4Q4dUDCAc&uact=5&oq=delgadez%20&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAMyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEMgUIABCABDIFCAAQgAQyBQgAEIAEOgQIABBDOgsIABCABBCxAxCDAToECC4QQzoRCC4QgAQQsQMQgwEQxwEQ0QM6BAgAEAM6CAguEIAEELEDOgUILhCABDoICC4QsQMQgwE6CwguEIAEEMcBEKMCOgsILhCABBCxAxCDAToLCC4QgAQQxwEQrwE6CAgAEIAEELEDOg0ILhCxAxCDARDUAhBDOhQILhCABBCxAxCDARDHARCvARDUAjoECAAQHjoICAAQHhAFEAo6BAgAEA1QAFjpEmDlFGgDcAB4AIAB0AGIAckOkgEFMS43LjSYAQCgAQE&sclient=gws-wiz)

¿Por qué existe esta diferencia? ¿Existe alguna regla para saber qué sufijo tengo que agregar (-ez o -idad) a un adjetivo cualquiera para crear el sustantivo derivado que signifique "la cualidad de ser algo (x)"?

Comment: Y también _-itud_ (apto->aptitud) y _-ura_ (blanco->blancura)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay que decir que no es un tema fácil de tratar debido entre otras cosas, a su complejidad, extensión y la diversidad de opiniones entre los autores, ya que la lingüística, tras el nacimiento de la "gramática generativa", (Chomsky: 1957), la investigación se orientó al estudio casi inexplorado de la "estructura sintáctica" y del campo de investigación en el análisis de la formación de palabras y dentro de este, en el área de la derivación nominal y adjetival de la sufijación.

Modernamente los sufijos se clasifican según la categoría gramatical de la que derivan, así se dividirán en;

- "deverbales" si derivan de verbos.
- "denominales" si derivan de nombres.
- "adjetivales" si derivan de adjetivos.

Formándose, por lo que respecta a la "*nominalización*", las clases de los sufijos "nominales deverbales", de los "nominales deadjetivales" y de los "nominales denominales".

Además, en lo que en lo que respecta a la "*adjetivación*", las de los sufijos "adjetivales deverbales" y de los sufijos "adjetivales denominales" .

---

Con respecto a la pregunta extraigo algunos extractos de la obra de Soledad Varela que resultan interesantes.

*SOLEDAD VARELA ORTEGA*

*MORFOLOGÍA LÉXICA: LA FORMACIÓN DE PALABRAS CON LA COLABORACIÓN DE SANTIAGO FABREGAT BARRIOS*.

Sufijos nominales que indican cualidad o conducta propia de:

- ada (gansada), -dad (igualdad) / -idad (facilidad) / -edad (so ledad) / -tad (libertad), -era (flojera), -ería (sosería), -ez (ñoñez) / -eza (tibieza), -ía (alegría), -ismo (partidismo), -itud (esclavitud), -or (grosor), -ura
  (tiesura).

Podemos formar derivados nominales con el significado de cualidad a partir de
ciertos adjetivos:

- rojo> roj-ez
- gordo> gord-ura
- feliz> felic-idad
- bueno> bon-dad,

*pero no así de otros*:

- francés> *francesez / *francesura
- dental> *dentalez / *dentalidad
- universitario > *universitariedad
- aéreo> *aeridad.

**¿Qué diferencia a este segundo grupo de adjetivos del primero?**

¿ Por qué motivo estos adjetivos no pueden dar lugar a nominalizaciones abstractas de cualidad?.

Los sustantivos en -ez,-ura e - i/e)dad, que indican cualidad, sólo se forman sobre adjetivos calificativos, que son aquellos que expresan propiedades o cualidades.

En el caso de los adjetivos relacionales* que se "recategorízan" como calificativos (musical, español, teatral), los nombres con el sufijo "-dad" o con los demás sufijos de cualidad, *sólo se refieren a las interpretaciones no relacionales* de los adjetivos correspondientes.

Podemos comprobar estos contrastes en los ejemplos:

- (a) un sonido muy musical> la musicalidad de un sonido, frente a la crítica musical>* la musicalidad de la critica;
- (b) Gibraltar español> la españolidad de Gibraltar, frente a filología española>, *la españolidad de la filología.
- (c) Gestos teatrales> la teatralidad de sus gestos, frente a la temporada teatral>, * la teatralidad de la temporada

---

Nota:

*Los adjetivos relacionales son los adjetivos que consiguen crear un vínculo o relación del nombre con un grupo de palabras. Es decir, son adjetivos que se unen al nombre siempre por detrás y que no lo modifican en número o en grado, sino que lo relacionan con un tema en concreto. Por ejemplo: música española*.

---

*Una lista de los sufijos se puede extraer del Gran Diccionario de la Lengua Española Larousse y del Diccionario Etimológico de los sufijos españoles*.

Answer (score 3):

¡Hola!

Desconozco si existe una regla para saber qué sufijo corresponde (hasta donde se y he buscado, no la hay). En cualquier caso aquí añado una lista de sufijos utilizados para denotar "cualidad de"

Los sufijos que denotan cualidad son los siguientes:

```
-acidad:   locuacidad, vivacidad
-ería:     soltería, tacañería, bobería
-eza:      franqueza, sutileza, bajeza
-ía:       cofradía
-idad:     rotundidad
-tud:      amplitud
-ura:      tersura
-dad:      frialdad
-ez:       idiotez
-icia:     malicia
-or:       picor
```

Fuente: https://www.gramaticas.net/2012/06/ejemplos-de-sufijos-de-cualidad.html

Comment: En lugar de "-az", debería ser "-acidad" (locuacidad, vivacidad). "locuaz" y "vivaz" son adjetivos, no sustantivos.

Comment: Totalmente de acuerdo @Gustavson. Ya he corregido el fallo. ¡Muchas gracias!